# Get prior date based on criteria in R

Tags: r

I have data like below.

```
df <- data.frame(CustID = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,5),
CustName = c("Fred","Maria","John","Mark", "Julia","Fred","Julia"),
ServiceDate = c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14','2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2010-12-14','2008-3-14'), stringsAsFactors = F)

df$ServiceDate <- as.Date(df$ServiceDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

df

  CustID CustName ServiceDate
1      1     Fred  2010-11-01
2      2    Maria  2008-03-25
3      3     John  2007-03-14
4      4     Mark  2010-11-01
5      5    Julia  2008-03-25
6      1     Fred  2010-12-14
7      5    Julia  2008-03-14
```

and I need to figure out a way to get the prior value based on CusID and ServiceDate so that I get a something like this:

```
  CustID CustName ServiceDate PriorServiceDate
1      1     Fred  2010-11-01             <NA>
2      2    Maria  2008-03-25             <NA>
3      3     John  2007-03-14             <NA>
4      4     Mark  2010-11-01             <NA>
5      5    Julia  2008-03-25       2008-03-14
6      1     Fred  2010-12-14       2010-11-01
7      5    Julia  2008-03-14             <NA>
```

I have tried using sqldf with no success.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr` I think this should solve your problem.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(CustID) %>%
    arrange(ServiceDate) %>%
    mutate(PriorServiceDate = lag(ServiceDate))

Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
Groups: CustID

  CustID CustName ServiceDate PriorServiceDate
1      1     Fred  2010-11-01             <NA>
2      1     Fred  2010-12-14       2010-11-01
3      2    Maria  2008-03-25             <NA>
4      3     John  2007-03-14             <NA>
5      4     Mark  2010-11-01             <NA>
6      5    Julia  2008-03-14             <NA>
7      5    Julia  2008-03-25       2008-03-14
```

Please note this assumes you are looking at the prior date with `lag`, not the minimum date (unsure with your question).

If you did want `min` then you can easily index the others out

```
df2 <- df %>%
    group_by(CustID) %>%
    arrange(ServiceDate) %>%
    mutate(PriorServiceDate = min(ServiceDate))

df2$PriorServiceDate[which(df2$ServiceDate == df2$PriorServiceDate)] = NA

Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
Groups: CustID

  CustID CustName ServiceDate PriorServiceDate
1      1     Fred  2010-11-01             <NA>
2      1     Fred  2010-12-14       2010-11-01
3      2    Maria  2008-03-25             <NA>
4      3     John  2007-03-14             <NA>
5      4     Mark  2010-11-01             <NA>
6      5    Julia  2008-03-14             <NA>
7      5    Julia  2008-03-25       2008-03-14
```

Comment: I think you `lag` solution is fine because OP specifically asked for *prior* date rather *minimum*. Alex just unnecessarily over complicated it.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the `dplyr` answer, this uses base R and gets the minimum date rather than the lag.

First get the first service date per customer.

```
first.service <- with(df, aggregate(ServiceDate,
                                    by=list(CustID=CustID, CustName=CustName),
                                    FUN=min))
```

Now merge it with the original data frame.

```
both <- merge(df, first.service, by=c("CustID", "CustName"))
```

You can set prior service date to `NA` for customers with no prior service like so:

```
both$x[with(both, ServiceDate == x)] <- NA
```

Then rename the column:

```
colnames(both)[4] <- "PriorServiceDate"
```

Answer (score 1):

With sqldf it can be done with a left self join.  For a particular row from `b` keep rows from `a` whose `CustID` is the same as the `CustID` from `b` and whose `ServiceDate` is less.  Then of those `a` rows take the one whose `ServiceDate` is greatest.  This makes no assumptions regarding the ordering of the input.  It keeps the original ordering of rows but if that is not important then  the `order by` line can be omitted:

```
library(sqldf)

DF <- sqldf("select b.CustID, 
                    b.CustName, 
                    b.ServiceDate ServiceDate__Date, 
                    max(a.ServiceDate) PriorDate__Date
             from df b 
             left join df a 
               on b.ServiceDate > a.ServiceDate and b.CustID = a.CUSTID 
             group by b.CustID, b.ServiceDate
             order by b.rowid", 
        method = "name__class")
```

giving:

```
> DF
  CustID CustName ServiceDate   PriorDate
1      1     Fred  2010-11-01        <NA>
2      2    Maria  2008-03-25        <NA>
3      3     John  2007-03-14        <NA>
4      4     Mark  2010-11-01        <NA>
5      5    Julia  2008-03-25  2008-03-14
6      1     Fred  2010-12-14  2010-11-01
7      5    Julia  2008-03-14        <NA>
```